# Run batch file located on another machine

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins installed on my machine. I have a batch file which is located on another machine and I want to run it in my Jenkins job.

What steps are required to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the batch file on the other machine, the solution is to split your job in 2 jobs:

- One running on your machine
- The second running on the other machine to launch your batch file

The other solution is to store your batch file in SVN or Git, and to pool it on your machine with your Jenkins job.